# Starting Hasura GraphQL engine Docker image

Tags: docker, graphql, hasura

I'm trying to get started with [Hasura GraphQL engine](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/index.html) running locally on OSX in Docker and connecting to an existing database but I am having trouble finding the container or the Hasura console.

Here's what I have:

```
docker -v
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
docker images
hasura/graphql-engine v1.0.0
hasura version
INFO hasura cli version=v1.0.0
```

Here's my start script (docker-run.sh) which sets up the port and environment variables for Hasura:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 \
-e HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://someuser:somepassword@host.docker.internal:5432/somedb \
-e HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE=true \
hasura/graphql-engine:latest
```

Running `./docker-run.sh` returns a 64 char hex string, which I assume to be the container ID, but I cannot see a container when I run `docker ps`, and nothing loads on `http://localhost:8080/console`.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE 1**

I can see the container when I run `docker ps -a` - it has a status of `exited(1)` (which means application error).

I can see in the logs:

```
{"path":"$","error":"pgcrypto extension is required, but the current user doesn’t have permission to create it. Please grant superuser permission, or setup the initial schema via https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/deployment/postgres-permissions.html","code":"postgres-error"}
```

I have followed the instructions for setting up the initial schema but the result of running `./docker-run.sh` has not changed.

**UPDATE 2**

I did not realise that the **pgcrypto** extension had to be installed on the specific database. Now that I have done so, the logs look healthy - although I am still unable to access the console when I run `hasura console`.

Here's my **config.yaml**:

`endpoint: http:localhost:8080`

...and the resulting error:

```
FATA[0001] version check: failed to get version from server: failed making version api call: Get http:localhost:8080/v1/version: http: no Host in request URL
```

Again, what am I missing?

**UPDATE 3**

Changed config.yaml...

`endpoint: http://localhost:8080`

Whoops (blush).

OK, it's working :)

Comment: what's the output of below commands: `docker ps -a ` and `docker logs <64_char_hex_string>`?

Comment: Ahh OK, I can see a few entries for Hasura when I run ps -a. The logs show `...pgcrypto extension is required, but the current user doesn’t have permission to create it...` which I will look up next. Thanks!

Comment: So everything is OK now? And the problem was "http://" ?